# validating href link to file

Tags: jquery, validation, href

I am using JQuery to dynamically add a link for an image file.

```
+ "<td><a class='IconButton' id='trkimg" + k + "' href='IMSTORE\/" + trackings[k].Image + "'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-image'></span></td>"
```

This code checks that a value was returned from the database and hides the link if nothing was returned:

```
if (trackings[k].Image == null) { $("#trkimg" + k).html(""); $("#trkimg" + k).removeClass('CustomButton'); }
```

How can I use JQuery to validate that the file returned actually exists, and if it doesn't exist, display a different image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of what SeanJA suggested, you could use ajax to 'test' for the image, then actually append the image in the `success` callback, or try another in the `error` callback.

You're requesting the image twice, but maybe it is cached after the first try. Not sure.

If you want to actually use the image returned, it needs to be encoded. Here's a link to instructions on how to do it. Haven't tried it, though.

http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html

```
    var imageURI = "http://mydomain.com/myimage.jpg";
    $.ajax(
        {
            type:'get',
            dataType:'image/jpeg',
            url:imageURI,
            success:function() { $('body').append('<img src="' + imageURI + '" />'); },
            error:function() { /* Change url in imageURI variable, and try again */ }
        }
    );
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot see the files on your server. You could do an ajax request to something server side to check if the file exists I guess.

Comment: Is it possible to catch the 404 error and redirect to a different image?